# How to gracefully capture exceptions from timer events?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

In an ASP Net Core 2 MVC app, I am using [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/) `BackGroundService` (via `IHostingService`) with the below implementation to update singleton gauge objects for a real-time dashboard. However, I don't know of a good way to ensure I capture any exceptions thrown when the `Update` event is fired.

Note: I am aware of `AppDomain.UnhandledException` but find it to be more of a sledgehammer approach and would like something easier to maintain and scale.

Or, is there an entirely better way to periodically update data in a background task in `ASP.NET Core 2`?

```
public class GaugeUpdater : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly List<IUpdateable> _updatables;

    private Timer _timer;

    public GaugeUpdater (IEnumerable<IUpdateable> updateables)
    {
        _updatables = updateables.ToList();
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        if (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await InitializeUpdateables();

            SetTimer();
        }
    }

    private void SetTimer()
    {
        const int intervalMilliseconds = 60_000;

        var interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, intervalMilliseconds);
        _timer = new Timer(UpdateAll, null, interval, interval);
    }

    private async Task InitializeUpdateables()
    {
        var tasks = _updatables.Select(x => x.Initialize()).ToList();

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async void UpdateAll(object state)
    {
        // TODO: Find way to handle exceptions, as awaiting async void makes it impossible for caller to catch.
        // AppDomain.UnhandledException is possible but hard to maintain and handle in this scope.
        _updatables.ForEach(async x => await x.Update());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`async void` can work for event handlers. Create and event and raise it with the timer. From there you should be able to await async tasks and handle exceptions

```
public class GaugeUpdater : BackgroundService {
    private readonly List<IUpdateable> _updatables;
    private Timer _timer;

    public GaugeUpdater (IEnumerable<IUpdateable> updateables) {
        _updatables = updateables.ToList();
        Updating += OnUpdating; //Subscribe to event
    }

    private event EventHandler Updating = delegate { };
    private async void OnUpdating(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        try {
            var tasks = _updatables.Select(x => x.Update());
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        } catch {
            //TODO: Logging???
        }
    }

    private void UpdateAll(object state) {
        Updating(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Raise event
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
        if (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
            await InitializeUpdateables();
            SetTimer();
        }
    }

    private void SetTimer() {
        const int intervalMilliseconds = 60_000;
        var interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, intervalMilliseconds);
        _timer = new Timer(UpdateAll, null, interval, interval);
    }

    private async Task InitializeUpdateables() {
        var tasks = _updatables.Select(x => x.Initialize()).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```